# how will i able to do a certain div using ajax that will only load on a certain div using codeigniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Hi i have this certain div which is "you have 1 messages" which will increment if the users sends a message and i want that if i received a message, without refreshing the page it will appear to the certain div "you have 2 messages" i have already the code for the backend on this. and it works but with only i want that to be in ajax that only certain div will refresh not the whole page. How to get a response using codeigniter? Heres my code below

```
 $this->data['getNumberOfMessages'] = $this->mm->getNumberOfMessages($this->data['id']);


    $this->data['countNumber'] = $this->data['getNumberOfMessages'];

   $response = array(
              'status'=>'ok',
              'StatusMessages'=>$this->data['countNumber']

            );
      //print_r($response);
       $this->output

            ->set_output(json_encode(array($response)));
```

my views

```
<tr>
                    <th>
                    <a href="#" id="<?php echo $id; ?>" data-messageid="<?php echo $id; ?>" data-href="<?php echo base_url().'messages'?>" title="messages">
                    You have 
                    <span class="badge"><?php echo $countNumber; ?></span>
                    message(s)</a>
                  </th>
```

and my jquery ajax code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
     var id =$(this).data("messageid");
      $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: $(this).data("href"),
         data: {
          messageId : id,
          userId : "<?php echo $id; ?>"
        },                  
        success: function(data){
          alert(data.StatusMessages );
          $("#" + id).html("<?php echo 'You have ' ?>:" + data.StatusMessages + "messages");

        }
      });
  });
</script>
```

and ive noticed that in my alert it is undefined. and i think that no data was passed.Can someone help me figured this out?. Ive been stucked here for 3 days.
Any help is muchly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, setInterval to update the message regularly.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var autoLoad; 
$(document).ready(function(){
    var id =$(this).data("messageid");
    autoLoad = setInterval(function(){loadAjax(id);}, 4000);
    //That means you will request to get your message each 4 seconds.
});
function loadAjax(id)
{
  $.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: $(this).data("href"),
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: {
      ajax: "yes"
    },     
    success: function(data){
      alert(data);
      console.log(data.StatusMessages);
      //$("#" + id).html("<?php echo 'You have ' ?>:" + data.StatusMessages + "messages");
      $("#" + id + ' span.badge').html(data.StatusMessages);
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

On the server, you just return something like this:

```
$responseOnject = new stdClass();
$responseOnject->status = 'ok';
$responseOnject->StatusMessages=$this->data['countNumber'];


if ($this->input->get("ajax") == "yes")
{
    echo json_encode($responseOnject);
    exit;
    //If you don't exit right here. It will return all your page back to browser
    //This section is just for ajax request
}
```

Comment: i already add this line of code
 dataType: "JSON", //You lack this thing

Comment: 3000 means three seconds. At least, you press F12 on the browsers and open tab network to see what response.

Comment: If It still doesn't work. Give me your teamviewer ID. I will fix it for you.

Comment: yes it will load 3seconds but my certain div does not update using ajax

Comment: hmm i dont have a teamviewe in here what do you think is wrong on thia part?

Comment: Post here what you received from the server each 3 seconds.

Comment: $("#<?php echo $id; ?>").html("<?php echo 'You have ' ?>:" + data.StatusMessages + "messages"); It should be like this.

Comment: change //print_r($response); by echo json_encode($response); exit;

Comment: if It's still doesn't work. Please install teamviewer and give me your id. I will fix it for you.

Comment: i change that but it will display {"StatusMessage":0}

Comment: i look with the response and it works it will change to 1 messages but with the html codes also

Comment: without using set interval 3000?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62517/discussion-on-answer-by-user2853290-how-will-i-able-to-do-a-certain-div-using-aj).

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML looks fine, your PHP code try editing as follows to make an object instead of array:

```
$this->data['getNumberOfMessages'] = $this->mm->getNumberOfMessages($this->data['id']);
$this->data['countNumber'] = $this->data['getNumberOfMessages'];

$responseOnject = new stdClass();
$responseOnject->status = 'ok';
$responseOnject->StatusMessages=$this->data['countNumber'];

$this->output->set_output(json_encode($responseOnject));
```

then in your 'jQuery AJAX' (Javascript actually) code, replace [i have no idea why you have PHP echo here]:

```
$("#" + id).html("<?php echo 'You have ' ?>:" + data.StatusMessages + "messages");
```

with:

```
$("#" + id+ ' span.badge').html(data.StatusMessages);
```

Also do give a proper url for AJAX to work instead of this:

```
url: $(this).data("href"),
```

Wish you luck :)

Comment: hi ive got error on this line of code
$responseOnject->StatusMessages'=$this->data['countNumber'];

Comment: oh just remove the apostrophe (single quote), i will edit my answer

Comment: are you still getting 'undefined' in your alert?

Comment: your code wont work ... i tried to alert(data.statusmessage) undefined

Comment: it seems that i already have this line of code
url: $(this).data("href"),

Comment: You are supposed to change it give the url of the php page

Comment: ahh okay i see ill try to change to url in php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62512/discussion-between-sameer-shemna-and-hello).

Comment: hi what seems to be a problem here

Comment: hi you there? can we chat in the discussion?

Comment: please make a jsfiddle for it and i ll try to help